# Compare 2 columns in a dataframe - Error: levels sets of factors are different

Tags: r

Contex: I'm trying to compare 2 columns from a dataframe in R using `ifelse`, but I keep getting `Error in Ops.factor(train_pca$snv_data.clade, train_pca$cladePredictedPCA) : level sets of factors are different` even though they are both factors and should have the same levels? I was also trying to pass the factors to characters to a new dataframe using `sapply`, but I keep getting `NULL`

This is some of the rows from the data frame:

```
snv_data.clade<fctr>                                           cladePredictedPCA<fctr>
1   19A 0.8180204   -6.317568   -1.013538559    0.5003878696    0.55308989  19A
2   20B 0.7855081   -5.202732   -0.148096886    -1.1426848702   0.64047215  20B
3   20A 0.5976934   -5.770061   -0.907229952    0.6297763798    0.43794949  20A
4   20B 0.7855081   -5.202732   -0.148096886    -1.1426848702   0.64047215  20B
5   20A 0.5976934   -5.770061   -0.907229952    0.6297763798    0.43794949  20A
6   20A 0.5976934   -5.770061   -0.907229952    0.6297763798    0.43794949  20A
10  20B 0.9791950   -5.004659   -0.269716476    -1.0581837861   0.82622079  20B
11  20B 0.8061000   -5.296302   -0.170322793    -1.1629464593   0.69397422  20B
12  20B 0.7855081   -5.202732   -0.148096886    -1.1426848702   0.64047215  20B
```

I was also trying to use `which`, but something similar pops up. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please use `dput()` to provide the example data in a usable format?

Comment: Could it be that one of your factors contains NA values and the other doesn't? If so, at some point before the comparison, the NAs might have been transformed into a factor level. What do you get when you inspect the `levels()` of each factor?

Comment: Could also try droplevels() on the factor variables in case they have inherited any empty levels you can't see. An empty level might be causing the mismatch.